# Highlighting duplicate "Q&A" in excel but not first

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

```
What is the color of the sky?
A. Blue
B. Grey
C. Green
A

Which is the Capital of Japan?
A. Alabama
B. Alaska
C. Tokyo
B

What is the letter next to C
A. D
B. E
C. F
A

Which is the Capital of Japan?
A. Alabama
B. Alaska
C. Tokyo
B
```

i have about 1000 Questions, and i would like to remove the duplicates OR highlight the duplicate ones except for the first, so i could delete them.

The Question is in one row, Answer is in the next row. 
[Sample here](http://s23.postimg.org/9fo5kac8r/123123.png)

Please help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hello, Please do note that the help page on "how to ask" states you should always ask yourself: "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?". as well, from the help page on "On Topic Questions" - "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." Please could you include more detail on what you've tried so far and why that has not worked out?

Comment: I have used several macro scripts and failed to so, which is why i came here.. yes, i've gone through the topics and havent found a solution yet.

Comment: Please keep in mind that it is much easier for us, and there for you will have better chances of getting a good answer if: you include what in particular you have tried. `I have used several macro scripts and failed to so` what sort of scripts were those that you tried? what sort of approach did these scripts take? what went wrong with the scripts? (did you get run time errors, data errors, compile errors) and do show relevant code as well. All of this will help us help you work through any future problems :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NON VBA solution for highlighting duplicates:**

You can use [Conditiona Formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx).

Suppose your Q/A in range `A2:A12`.

**Step 1:**

Select range `A2:A12`. *With selected range* go to *Conditional Formatting --> New Rule...*

[image]

**Step 2:**

Select *"Use formula to detect which cells to format"*, enter formula `=AND(LEN(A2)>1,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,$A$1:$A1,0)))` and choose desired format. Click *OK*.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**Notes:**

1. If your Q/A list starts from row 1, apply CF only for questions starts from row 2 (formula requirements). Шt will not affect the result because in the first row you can't have duplicate.
2. In formula `=AND(LEN(A2)>1,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,$A$1:$A1,0)))` part `LEN(A2)>1` exclude answers from duplicate search (because they could be duplicate for different answers)

---

**VBA soluton for highlighting/deleting duplicates:**

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rngToDel As Range

    'change Sheet1 to suit
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'change column A to column where your Q/A list
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'loop throught cells from lastrow to row ¹2
        For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
            'if it's question and not answer
            If Len(.Range("A" & i)) > 1 Then
                'if it is a duplicate
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Range("A" & i), .Range("A1:A" & i - 1), 0)) Then
                    If rngToDel Is Nothing Then
                        'it's a duplicate - remember both question and answer
                        Set rngToDel = Union(.Range("A" & i), .Range("A" & i + 1))
                    Else
                        Set rngToDel = Union(rngToDel, .Range("A" & i), .Range("A" & i + 1))
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If Not rngToDel Is Nothing Then
        'highlight entire row with red
        rngToDel.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        'or delete entire row
        rngToDel.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```